# Pass the clicked element's data by using eventbus in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Im pretty new to Vue.js, thank you for your understanding. Im setting up a Vue project where I want to show Patients and their data. I want to tell from the beginning that Im not planning to use Vuex :)

My project has 3 layers.

Home.vue file where I import the data (patients)

Next layer is Patients.vue component where I have a for loop and output all the patients. In this case, I am getting the patient Array by using props.

And the last layer is called ViewPatient.vue view. What I want to do here is showing more details of the clicked Patient.  I want to inherit for example the name to make one more call to the endpoint to retrieve some observations of the patient. For example: endpoint/patient/(theName) <-- the name should come from the previous Patients.vue component.

I tried a lot of different approaches: eventbus, dynamic router and data-attrbutes.

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <keep-alive>
      <Patients :PatientsData="PatientsData" />
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import PatientsData from "../data/messages";
import Patients from "../components/Patients.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  data() {
    return {
      PatientsData: PatientsData
    };
  },

  components: {
    Patients
  }
};
</script>
```

Patients.vue (component)

```
<template>
  <div v-if="PatientsData.length > 0">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div v-for="PatientData in PatientsData" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3" :key="PatientData.content" :data-id="PatientData.content" @click.prevent="passPatientData" >
        <router-link to="/patient" >
          <div class="col-12 patientsTiles p-4">
            <p class="patientsName">
              <span>Navn</span>
              {{ PatientData.content }}
            </p>
            <p class="patientsCPR">
              <span>CPR.nr</span>
              {{ PatientData.subject }}
            </p>
            <p class="patientsAge">
              <span>Alder</span>
              {{PatientData.age}}
            </p>
            <i :class="['fa', 'fa-star', {important: PatientData.isImportant}]"></i>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import router from "../main";
import { eventBus } from "../main";
export default {
  props: {
    PatientsData: Array,
  },
  data(){
    return{
      patientName: ""
    }
  },


  methods: {
    passPatientData() {
      this.patientName = this.PatientData;
      alert(this.patientName);

      eventBus.$emit("passPatientData", this.patientName);
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

ViewPatient.vue (view)

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>The Patient detail</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import { eventBus } from "../main";

export default {
  props: {
    // patientId:{
    //     type: String
    // } 
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedPatient : ""
    };
  },

  created() {  
      eventBus.$on("passPatientData", data  => {  
        this.selectedPatient = data;
        // console.log("yeaah");

 })}
}
</script>
```

IMO, the problem is lying on the passPatientData function. 
this.PatientData is empty and I dont know how to pass the clicked element's data to the empty string (this.patientName), so I can emit it to the eventbus

```
passPatientData() {
      this.patientName = this.PatientData;
      alert(this.patientName);

      eventBus.$emit("passPatientData", this.patientName);
    }
```

Comment: Several questions: 1. Where is `this.PatientData` empty? Have you tried placing a debugger each step of the way to see where it gets 'lost'? 2. Where is there an instance of `ViewPatient.vue`? Looks like it has no name and I don't see it in the templates anywhere.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors 1: As you can see above I am alerting this.partientName which is this.PatientData. The result is undefined.

2: I've now added the name, but it doesnt change anything. Btw im using router, so I am actually giving names to in the router/index.js file. 

Hope it was your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach which worked for me (few changes):

@bbsimonbb, thank you for the answer, but I´m not going to use that approach, because its a bit overkill when compared to my small task.

In Patients.vue while looping patients, I have modified the click event:
Im actually passing the single element that is being clicked, which solved med a lot of time.

```
<div v-for="PatientData in storedPatients" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3" :data-id="PatientData.content" @click="passPatientData(PatientData)" >
```

Before:

```
  @click="passPatientData"
```

After:

```
@click="passPatientData(PatientData)"
```

And then in my event bus im able to "work" with the data im passing:

```
methods: {
    passPatientData(element) {
      this.patientName = element.content;
      alert(this.patientName);

      eventBus.$emit("passPatientData", this.patientName);
    }
  }
```

The purpose is to pass the patientName to ViewPatient.vue file by using eventbus and call a new endpoint which looks like this: endpoint/patient/(patientName) . The result of the endpoint will then be the details of the single patient that has been clicked in patients.vue

It´s working. Hope it can be useful for others that is struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've decided not to use Vuex. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use a store. The simplest store is just an object in the data of your root Vue, passed around via provide/inject. Put your shared data in there.

This is a much simpler pattern to get your head around than an event bus. You get the shared state right out of Vue components, and because it's just an object, that does nothing but store state, you will be more in control of what you have and how it's working.

```
// Home.vue
export default {
    name: "home",
    provide: { mySharedData: this.mySharedData },
    data() {
        return {
            mySharedData: {
                patientData: {}
            }
        };
    },
    created() {
        fetch("http://patientData")
            .then(response.json)
            .then((patientData) => this.mySharedData.patientData = patientData)
    }
    ...

// Then, in all other components of your app...
export default {
        inject: ['mysharedData'],
        ...
    }
```

This way, you'll be making full use of Vue reactivity to propagate your changes. You'll need to understand how Vue makes properties reactive. In particular, you can't just assign new props in mySharedData. The simplest way is to make sure all the props are there to start with. To do it on the fly, [use Vue.set()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: Yeah you are right :) And that doesn't sound bad. Do you have concrete example? Or something I could read?